# Convert math in org file to markdown file correctly

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to convert/export a org file to Markdown. Most Markdown supports math with `$x^2$` or `$$x^2$$`. I tried `ox-gfm` and `pandoc`, but they don't seem to handle it correctly:

org file:

```
\[x^2\]  
$$x^2$$  
$x^2$  
\(x^2\)
$x^2$
```

exported markdown file:

```
\[x^2\]  
\[x^2\]  
\(x^2\)  
\(x^2\)
\(x^2\)
```

None of these show up as math in a markdown file (correct would be `$x^2$`).

Does anyone know how to get the correct behavior?
Note: I use spacemacs.

Answer (score 1):

The markdown exported in org is generic: it does not handle the many flavors that are extant. You are probably better off using `pandoc` to do conversions to markdown:

```
 pandoc -r org -w markdown_github foo.org > foo.md
```

You can find what formats `pandoc` supports with the `--list-input-formats` and `--list-output-formats` options.